# Как правильно загрузить и потом прочитать не текстовый файл на GitHub с помощью kohsuke github api?

Tags: java, android, github-api

```java
//Текстовые файлы загружаю следующим образом. Строка json делается библиотекой GSON

gitHub.getRepository(Constants.REPO_NAME).getFileContent("Files/" + item.getData().get("day") + "." + item.getData().get("month") + ".json").update(json, "File updated");

//А потом получаю с гитхаба так:

gitHub.getRepository(Constants.REPO_NAME).getFileContent("Files/" + item.getData().get("file").read();
```

С текстовыми всё ОК. А теперь нетекстовый (если быть точным, картинка):

```
//Сначала получаю строку из файла. Пробовал несколько способов
String fileContent = "";

//1 сп. - библиотека Apache Commons. Пробовал указывать кодировки UTF-8, UTF-16 и ASCII
fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
//2 сп.
fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
//3 сп.
fileContent = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
//4 сп.
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] buf = new byte[in.available()+1];
in.read(buf, 0, in.available());
fileContent = new String(buf);

//Загружаю файл на гитхаб
gitHub.getRepository(Constants.REPO_NAME).getFileContent(filePath).update(fileContent, "File updated");

//Потом получаю файл так:
InputStreamReader inputRdr = null;
                                               
try {
    inputRdr = new InputStreamReader(gitHub.getRepository(Constants.REPO_NAME).getFileContent("Files/" + item.getData().get("file")).read());
} catch (IOException e) {}

try {
while (inputRdr.read() != -1) {                                                    
    fileStr.append(inputRdr.read());
}

} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Но получаю ошибку при чтении файла:

```
2023-10-19 19:34:04.884 10991-11110 hometask.viewe          special.hometask.viewer              E  [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
2023-10-19 19:34:04.887 10991-11110 AndroidRuntime          special.hometask.viewer              E  FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-15
                                                                                                    Process: special.hometask.viewer, PID: 10991
                                                                                                    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unrecognized encoding: none
                                                                                                        at org.kohsuke.github.GHContent.read(GHContent.java:198)
                                                                                                        at special.hometask.viewer.ViewPagerAdapter$1$1$2$1.run(ViewPagerAdapter.java:260)
2023-10-19 19:34:04.969 10991-11110 Process                 special.hometask.viewer              I  Sending signal. PID: 10991 SIG: 9
2023-10-19 19:34:05.027  1079-1482  InputDispatcher         system_server                        E  channel '3c7fad4 special.hometask.viewer/special.hometask.viewer.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2023-10-19 19:34:05.027  1079-1482  InputDispatcher         system_server                        E  channel '10c1337 special.hometask.viewer/special.hometask.viewer.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2023-10-19 19:34:05.027  1079-1482  InputDispatcher         system_server                        E  channel '71ed0b2 special.hometask.viewer/special.hometask.viewer.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2023-10-19 19:34:05.124  1079-2393  WindowManager           system_server                        E  win=Window{71ed0b2 u0 special.hometask.viewer/special.hometask.viewer.MainActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true
2023-10-19 19:34:05.165  1079-1456  WindowManager           system_server                        E  win=Window{10c1337 u0 special.hometask.viewer/special.hometask.viewer.MainActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true
2023-10-19 19:34:05.216  1989-12373 DollieAdapterService    com.huawei.systemserver              E  notifyActivityState pkg:special.hometask.viewer/special.hometask.viewer.MainActivity state:18 fg:false mUid:11640
```

Возникает в строке

```
in = gitHub.getRepository(Constants.REPO_NAME).getFileContent("Files/" + item.getData().get("file")).read();
```

Файл в репозитории **есть**, я проверил

Answer (score 0):

Если файл не текстовый, то за каким вы его в текст перегоняете - читайте/пишите напрямую байтовый поток/массив.
Отправляем:

```java
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
gitHub.getRepository(Constants.REPO_NAME).getFileContent(filePath)).update(fileContent, "File updated");
```

Принимаем:

```java
InputStream stream = gitHub.getRepository(Constants.REPO_NAME).getFileContent("Files/" + item.getData().get("file").read();
Files.copy(stream, file.toPath());
```

Comment: Странно, но почему-то при получении файла проблема та же самая остаётся

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос лог ошибки и код, на котором она возникает

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Я не использовал эту библиотеку и сам github-api, дальше подсказать не могу, но беглый взгляд в доки говорит что таким способом можно получать контент файлов размером до мегабайта. Свыше, судя по всему, нужно загружать по ссылке, которую можно взять методом [`getDownloadUrl()`](https://github-api.kohsuke.org/apidocs/org/kohsuke/github/GHContent.html#getDownloadUrl()). А вот как записывать большие файлы в репозиторий не понятно.

Comment: https://github-api.kohsuke.org/apidocs/index.html - доки-то есть, но они мало полезные. Поскольку это обёртка к github-api, нужно ещё доки к REST смотреть: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents